# issues with cat not accepting filename as a variable

Tags: variables, cat

im writing a terminal alias function and having issues getting the contents of a file. Im using a mac, not sure if that makes a difference for this.

why dose this command not work?

```
setupfile=~/test.txt
contents1=$( cat ${setupfile} );
```

but this dose?

```
vhostdefault=$(cat ~/test.txt );
```

any insight or help would be amazing. cheers

Comment: I found out the answer. Bash scripts dont understand the ~ filepath.  

You can set the folder path of ~ to variable and use that. This is some linux bash code I have used to assign the ~ location to $userDir. This may not work for mac but a similar approach should.

`eval userDir=~$(whoami); # get user folder location`

so the blow code should work

`eval userDir=~$(whoami);
vhostdefault=$(cat ${userDir}/test.txt );`